# Haskell permutations matching criteria

Tags: haskell

How would one do the following in Haskell:

> Return all permutations of a list where one element comes before the
>   another element (cannot assume that elements of the list can be
>   ordered)?

My solution was to do:

```
sLeftOf l r lss =
    [ ls
    | ls <- lss
    , DL.findIndex (l==) ls <= DL.findIndex (r==) ls
    ]
```

for *somewhere to the left of* and

```
sDirectLeftOf l r lss =
  [ls
  | ls <- lss
  , DL.findIndex (l==) ls  == fmap (\x-> x - 1) (DL.findIndex (r==) ls)
  ]
```

for *directly* to the left of which works,

```
*Main Lib> sLeftOf 2 3 (permutations [1..3])
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]

*Main Lib> sDirectLeftOf 2 3 (permutations [1..4])
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1,4],[4,2,3,1],[2,3,4,1],[4,1,2,3],[1,4,2,3]]
```

But I don't like these. The `findIndex` seems un-Haskelly and the `fmap` on the result of `findIndex` feels just wrong. Anyone has better ways to do this? For two lists there is a nice method using `guard`/`zip` and `elem`.

```
mylist = do
  x <- permutations ["a","b","c"]
  y <- permutations ["1","2","3"]

  leftOf "b" x "3" y
  return $ zip x y
  where
    leftOf x xs y ys = guard $ (x,y) `elem` zip xs (tail ys)
    leftOf' x xs y ys = guard $ (x,y) `elem` (aux xs (tail ys))
    aux a b@(_:ys) = (zip a b) ++ aux a ys
    aux _ []       = []

reqA = (map (map fst )) mylist
reqB = (map (map snd )) mylist
required = zip reqA reqB
```

The first `leftOf` is immediately to left of and the second is somewhere to the left of; but this won't work for a single list.

Comment: It's not clear what your criterion is for "better". I think your first solutions are perfectly clear and fine, but they are polynomial time algorithms. If you are concerned about performance I would suggest thinking about the problem by first taking the permutations of all elements _except the two you are interested in_, and then forming your final set from that. The "direct left of" case then becomes trivial.

Comment: It's hard to offer concrete suggestions unless you show your imports, particularly what `DL` is.

Answer (score 1):

> The findIndex seems un-Haskelly and the fmap on the result of findIndex feels just wrong.

There's nothing wrong with `fmap`.

One thing I *would* advise is replacing `(\x -> x - 1)` with `(minus 1)`. Also, `[ls | ls <- lss, p ls]` is probably best rewritten to use `filter`.

If you format your code more nicely, I think you'd find it reasonably appealing:

```
g = findIndex . (==)

p l r ls = g l ls <= g r ls

sLeftOf l r lss = filter (p l r) lss

sDirectLeftOf l r lss = filter (p l r) $ fmap (minus 1) (g ls)
```

> The first leftOf is immediately to left of and the second is somewhere to the left of; but this won't work for a single list.

Seems like a fairly contrived solution. `elem` and `zip` are still \$O(n)\$ so I don't think this accomplishes what you intended. If you're concerned about performance, I'd suggest using a keyed map so that lookups become \$O(\log n)\$ - searching an array will be \$O(n)\$ just like searching a list.

Also, you define

```
leftOf' x xs y ys = guard $ (x,y) `elem` (aux xs (tail ys))
aux a b@(_:ys) = (zip a b) ++ aux a ys
aux _ []       = []
```

which is not used anywhere. Passing the `-Wall` option to GHC will warn you any time you do something like this.